# Query database not using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

[image: dbdiagram]

i have a db diagram as shown above.
What I need to do is: 
Select a table which is as follows:
PatientId, Emergency.Name or Doctor Names, Patient.Address.

Explanation; I need A query which will return patient details and, if Patient has an emergency also add an emergency, if not select all doctor.Name into one row.

So, example:
[image: Example]

So, the first row was built because EmergencyId in table patient was null, while the second row had an emergency Id.

I need the query to simulate this. Using SSRS

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you explain how you want all dr names in one row?  What you have above appears to be three rows within a row, which is not possible in SQL Server.  Do you want to comma separate the names?  Can each DR Name be returned in a separate row?

Comment: Also, is there something on the front end that is consuming the results of this query?  If so, then You might want to change how these results are returned.

Comment: What about my first question?

Comment: No, I need exactly this layout with multiple values in one cell aligned vertically.

Comment: You can't format your data to look like that within SSRS?

Comment: SQL isn't optimized for putting multiple rows in one cell. You may need to write a user defined function that takes the same params as the outer query and concatenates the doctor names.  Likewise SQL is optimized for having the same data in columns. Getting the first row to return doctor names, and the second row/first column to return emergency names will require UNIONs.  I'm no SSRS guru, but this would might also be implementable with subreports (instead of udfs and UNIONS)

Comment: Thanks guys, can you at least explain me how to return this data in separate rows, so I can union later on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thanks guys, can you at least explain
>   me how to return this data in separate
>   rows, so I can union later on?

I believe this will return the data you want broken out into separate rows, returning Emergency if it exists and the Drs if it does not.  Good luck!

```
SELECT Distinct Coalesce(E.Name, D.Name) as VariableColumn, 
       P.PatientId,           
       P.Address
FROM Patient P 
  LEFT JOIN Emergency E 
    ON P.EmergencyId=E.EmergencyId
  LEFT JOIN PatientDoctor PD 
    ON P.PatientID=PD.PatientId
  LEFT JOIN Doctor D 
    ON PD.DoctorId=D.DoctorId
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really debug or work with your tables to check this, but here is a rough stab at something that should get you going:

```
SELECT P.PatientId, E.Name as 'EmergencyName', D.Name as 'DoctorName', P.Address
FROM Patient P 
  LEFT JOIN Emergency E ON P.EmergencyId=E.EmergencyId
  LEFT JOIN PatientDoctor PD ON P.PatientID=PD.PatientId
  LEFT JOIN Doctor D ON PD.DoctorId=D.DoctorId
ORDER BY P.PatientId, E.Name, D.Name, P.Address
```

Also, I'm no SQL Wizard. This should get the ball rolling, though.

- Can you test this query against your data?
- Does it return the desired results?

**EDIT:**

I just saw your comment about needing *this layout with multiple values in one cell aligned vertically*. That would require sub queries, and would be too much for me to write out.

Comment: This returns both Emergency name and Dr name regardless of whether there is an emergency.  It also returns a separate row for each Dr that is found.

Comment: Yes, as stated in the Edit, I'm not sure how best to place all doctors into a single cell. You're going to either have to write some strange looking script in SQL (using SQL functions to build a string to display) or override what is displayed on your form with a custom list that you create using the returned data.